# Is there a solution which would allow me to easily monitor/control the traffic for all devices on my network at the hostname level?

Tags: linux, networking, security, network-monitor, raspberry-pi

I originally asked this question in [a Superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1518759/how-can-i-easily-and-quickly-block-domains-across-my-whole-network-using-a-umatr) but it was removed and I was told to post here.

I'm a huge fan of the [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/) browser extension which allows you to control and limit which domains or subdomains your web browser is allowed to connect to when you're browsing a website. For example, `stackexchange.com` is not permitted to access `google-analytics.com` but is allowed to access `sstatic.net`.

I'm looking for a solution which would allow me to control the traffic from all devices on my network in a similar rule-based manner.

Some examples of the type of things I'd like to achieve:

- Block all devices on my network from accessing `google-analytics.com`, except for a single machine (e.g. a work computer).
- Block an IP camera from sending any external traffic except to certain pre-approved domains e.g. `update-check.manufacturer.com`
- Block an Amazon Kindle from accessing `amazon-adsystem.com`
- Block a "smart socket" from accessing any IP addresses except `123.123.123.123`

Bonus points if traffic rules can be defined using full request URLs (e.g. allow `example.com/good/*` but block `example.com/bad/*`.

I'm aware that solutions like PiHole exist but I would like something more flexible, particularly something which would allow me to easily set up custom rules on a per-device basis using either hostnames or IP addresses and which does *not* rely on DNS alone.

Besides, this type of request has already been specifically [marked as out of scope for PiHole](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/per-device-or-device-group-whitelist-to-keep-your-internet-connected-devices-under-control-with-pi-hole/3411).

Ideally the interface should be visual and easy to use instead of relying on text-based rules as with `iptables` etc.